# Exploring Dictionary Generic Property?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
// Example 1
var j = [2,5,"Hello"]
var dict1: [String : Array<Any>] = [:]
dict1   = ["arr" :  j ]
print(dict1["arr"]![0])


//Example 2
var k = [2,5,"Hello"]
var dict2: [String : Any] = [:]
    dict2   = ["arr" :  j ]
  let arr = dict2["arr"] as! Array
print(arr[0])
```

Why print statement in second example is showing this error? Why cant I print it and what does this Error means?

Comment: Any is not an array until you cast it

Comment: `dict2["array"]` is a `Any` object. doing `[someInt]` is called subscript. Why should `Any` allow doing `[someInt]` after it? You need to tell the compiler that it can, because `j` is an array.

Comment: Do you mean to use `= ["arr" : j ]` in Example 2? Or should that `j` be a `k`?

Comment: `(dict2["arr"] as? [Int])?[0]` or `(dict2["arr"] as? [Int])?.first`

Comment: Updated The Question please Recheck @DonMag

Comment: @Amey don't force cast it and you need to specify the array type

Comment: Updated Question Pls Check  @LeoDabus

Comment: @Amey have you tried googling type "Any has no subscript members"? That question was already asked thousand of times

Comment: yes No Solution Found @LeoDabus

Comment: @Amey kkkk So you didn't read any of them

Comment: @LeoDabus  READ BUT DIDNT GET CLEAR EXPLANATION .WHY EXAMPLE 2 IS NOT WORKING

Comment: I already posted the comment  
@Amey don't force cast it and you need to specify the array type

Comment: @LeoDabus IF DEFINE THE ARRAY TYPE AND I WANT TOUSE INTEGER AS WELL AS STRING IN THAT ARRAY SO HOW TO ACHIEVE IT ?

Comment: just cast to `[Any]` or define your dictionary type as `var dict2: [String : [Any]] = [:]`

Comment: Why DownVoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast to `Array` because Array is a generic type. You must cast to `Array<Any>` or `Array<Int>` or `[Int]` or `[Any]`

This works:

```
var j = [2,5,7]
var dict1: [String : Array<Any>] = [:]
dict1   = ["arr" :  j ]
print(dict1["arr"]![0])


//Example 2
var k = [2,5,7]
var dict2: [String : Any] = [:]
dict2   = ["arr" :  j ]
let arr = dict2["arr"] as! Array<Any>
print(arr[0])
```

While I do understand that this is just a sample code, I recommend to never force cast in swift but always use the optional casting `as?` to avoid tedious crashes. also force unwrapping should always be avoided.

Edit:

Sometimes playground doesn't work properly: when a previous error is fixed it still shows it as an error and remains in "running..." state for ever.

When this happens just reopen your playground and it should work.

Here is the proof that the code works:

[image]

Comment: I just told you. You cannot cast to Array. Array is a generic type.

Comment: affff Again You need to define the array type or use Any as your array type  `if let arr = dict2["arr"] as? [Any] {`

Comment: IF I USE THIS if let arr = dict2["arr"] as? [Any] THE SAME ERROR GENERATES

Comment: I'm sorry but no, it doesn't. restart your playground. works fine for me.

Comment: Please Check The Screenshot Updated in the question

Comment: Your screen shot shows cast as `Array` not `Array<Any>`

Comment: Why don't you simply use your first example where you define your dictionary value as `
[Any]`

Comment: if i cast it as Array<Any> it will Work i want to know the reason that why i have to cast this . @LeoDabus

Comment: How you expect the compiler to know that `Any` is an Array? You need to cast it first

Comment: @Amey I told you. Because `Array` is a generic type. You can't cast something to a generic type without specifiers.

Comment: Thanx For Solving The Problem I Really Appreciate Your efforts .

Comment: If you need more clarifications about this thing I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Pls Check my Updated ScreenShot Its Showing Error Written Same Code in your screenshot

Comment: It's not the same code. You are casting to `Any`, i'm casting to `[Any]` there is a huge difference

Answer (score 0):

Since `dict2` is declared as `[String : Any]`, the type of `dict2["arr"]` would be `Any` by default.

**Solution 01:**

cast the `Any` as an array of Ints (which matched with `j` type):

```
if let arr = dict2["arr"] as? [Int] {
    print(arr[0])
}
```

**Solution 02:**

Declare `dict2` as `[String : [Int]]` instead of `[String : Any]`:

```
var dict2: [String : [Int]] = [:]
```

Thus your code should work. However, keep in mind that for the safety, you should also do optional binding when accessing element from the dictionary, so instead of:

```
print(dict2["arr"]![0])
```

it should be:

```
if let arr = dict2["arr"] {
    print(arr[0])
}
```

Means that if "arr" does not match any value, it will not cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
    //Example 2
    var k = [2,5,7]
    var dict2: [String : Any] = [:]
    dict2   = ["arr" :  k ]

    if let anyArray = dict2["arr"] as? Array<Any> {
        print(anyArray[0])
    }
```

Comment: I HAVE ALREADY DONE THIS IN EXAMPLE ONE I WANT TO KNOW CONCEPT OF EXAMPLE 2 WHY IT IS NOT WORKING. I KNOW IT WILL WORK WHEN I DEFINE ARRAY<ANY> BUT WANT TO KNOW REASON OF EXAMPLE 2 ERROR

Comment: Well, no, that's not what you did... In Example #1, you declared `dict1: [String : Array<Any>]` ... in Example #2, you declared `dict2: [String : Any]`. That is not the same thing, and that's why you have to explicitly cast it to `Array<Any>`

Comment: Yes i know that if i cast it to Array<Any > it will work but i want to know the reason why i have to do this casting

Comment: ummm... because that's how the language is defined? You also cannot do something like `let 5 = "hello"` or `let x = 2; let y = x[3]`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your definition of `dict2` it is of type `[String:Any]` so `dict2["arr"]!` is not an array it's an Any.

If you want to use it as an array you need to explicitly say it's an array, you could do it like so:

1. Redefine `dict2` to be of type: `[String:Array<Any>]`. This way you can simply use `let are = dict2["arr"]` which will be of type Array
2. Or you need to force-downcast like so `let arr = dict2["arr"]! as! Array<Any>` telling the compiler that `arr` is of type `Array<Any>`

I would personally recommend option 1 if possible and if not you should try not to force-downcast but instead use an `if let` like this:

```
if let arr = dict2["arr"] as? Array<Any> {    
    print(arr[0])     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the type casting. You don't specify the type of Array items. The following code works as expected:

```
var k: [Any] = [2,5,"Hello"]
var dict2: [String : Any] = [:]
dict2   = ["arr" :  k ]
let arr = dict2["arr"] as! Array<Any>
print(arr[0])
```

Comment: I HAVE ALREADY DONE THIS IN EXAMPLE ONE I WANT TO KNOW CONCEPT OF EXAMPLE 2 WHY IT IS NOT WORKING. I KNOW IT WILL WORK WHEN I DEFINE ARRAY<ANY> BUT WANT TO KNOW REASON OF EXAMPLE 2 ERROR

Comment: Because Swift is a strongly typed language. dict2 has [String: Any] type. In this case `dict2["arr"]` has type Any. You are not able to call any method from Any object because it is typealias to the empty protocol (typealias Any = protocol<>), so, you need to cast it to array in order to call subscription like `arr[0]`. Array is a Generic structure, so you are not able to cast to Array: `dict2["arr"] as! Array`, you have to specify the generic item type. That is why you nee to use the following code: `let arr = dict2["arr"] as! Array<Any>`. Make sense?